# Publish python module to Azure Artifacts Feed from Git

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

How to publish self-written python module to Azure Artifacts Feed from Azure Repo with Azure Pipelines?

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

To publish Python packages produced by your build, you'll use [twine](https://pypi.org/project/twine/), a widely used tool for publishing Python packages. This guide covers how to do the following in your pipeline:

1. Install `twine` on your build agent

   [image: - script: 'pip install twine']
2. Authenticate `twine` with your Azure Artifacts feeds

   [image]
3. Use a custom task that invokes `twine` to publish your Python packages

   [image]

Check documentation below to get more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pypi?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml